# Переименовать все файлы в папке

Tags: python

При выполнении данного кода

```
import os
newfile = '1.txt'
for filee in os.listdir('C:/path'):
    print(filee)
    os.rename(filee, f'{newfile}')
```

У меня выходит ошибка

```
Текстовый документ (2).txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path.a.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.rename(filee, f'{newfile}')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'Текстовый документ (2).txt' -> 'baby.txt'
```

в папке находятся 3 файла .txt мне нужно их переименовать

Comment: т.е. вы хотите переименовать 3 файла и получить в итоге __единственный файл__, т.к. файловая система не позволяет иметь в одной директории два файла с одинаковым именем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
DIRECTORY = 'C:/testpath' # где находятся файлы

for i, f in enumerate(os.listdir(DIRECTORY)):
    new_filename = 'new_name_' + str(i) + '.txt' # названия, разумеется, должны быть разными
    print(f'Файл {f} переименован в {new_filename}')
    os.rename(
      DIRECTORY + '/' + f, # не забываем указывать директорию, где нужно изменить файл
      DIRECTORY + '/' + new_filename
    )
```

Проблема в том, что ваш код пытается найти `Текстовый документ (2).txt` в той же директории, что и исполняемый файл.

---

Результат работы программы
В консоли:

```
Файл gg.jar переименован в new_name_0.txt
Файл helloworld.txt переименован в new_name_1.txt
Файл main.py переименован в new_name_2.txt
Файл readme.doc переименован в new_name_3.txt

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 0.094 s
```

В директории:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
DIRECTORY = 'C:/testpath'
for i, s in enumerate(os.listdir(DIRECTORY)):
    os.rename(os.path.join(DIRECTORY, s), 
              os.path.join(DIRECTORY, '%s_%i.txt' % (s, i)))
```